# Как узнать полный путь до текущей директории в Ubuntu?

Tags: linux

Как узнать полный путь до текущей директории в Ubuntu?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

В терминале выполнить команду

```
pwd
```

Comment: **Print Working Directory** — так легче запомнится ;) + [man](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/upwd.htm).

Answer (score 12):

Кроме команды `pwd` можно использовать переменную окружения `$PWD`, которую определяют большинство интерпретаторов командной строки (`bash`, `dash`, `tcsh` и даже `busybox sh`) и изменяют её динамически при смене каталогов:

```
echo $PWD
```

Comment: Для Mac'овского стандартного Terminal'а тоже работает. По крайней мере начиная с Catalin'ы (на более ранних не проверял)